# How to reference image locations in css asset hosted on a different domain?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website at `http://www.link1.com` where all the php and images are, and I want to load the css from different website like `http://www.link2.com` (this doesn't host any of the css images)

I got the padding, margins, and arangement stuff from the css but not the images.

Do browsers restrict this? Is there any way for cross-domain css loading?

Comment: If the external CSS image references relative url's, it won't work. You must use absolute url's.

Comment: I know that but i have 2000 line`s in css and about 1500 are using images :(

Comment: Use your choice's editor and do a `find-replace` on all urls, simple. I'm supposing you have writting permissions on those CSS files.

Comment: @yoda Thank you man. I didn;t see that coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host your css on another host no problem. If the paddings etc are working then the css is loaded. If images are not working, check the paths specified in your css.

**Edit**: You should use absolute urls in your css definitions if the images are hosted on a different domain, i.e:

```
background: url('http://link2.com/path/to/image.jpg');
```

as relative paths are relative to the css location, not the parent page (except, apparently for IE, see Rob's answer below).

Comment: the paths are like this `background:url(../images/abc.jpg) no-repeat;` but the css is on `link2.com` and the images are on `link1.com` wich include the css from `link2.com`

Comment: @pufos: Have absolute URLs then.

Comment: I have like 2000 lines in my css ... :(

Comment: @pufos: I can't remember whether urls are relative to the css location or the parent page. Use absolute urls, ie background: url(http://link2.com...);

Comment: Yes i understand that now .. the only problem is that i have 2000 line in the css and ... uff ...

Comment: @Richard H urls in CSS are related to the file location, except for IE.

Comment: @Richard H yeah, I remembered it after posting :)

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers resolve relative paths in CSS as being relative to the CSS file's location (the exception is IE). If you are using relative paths and your images are on the pages host, that could be the source of your issue

Comment: Huh? I have never, ever had problems with relative CSS pathing in IE. Works just fine.

Comment: @ceejayoz see http://www.netvivs.com/how-to-fix-images-and-css-relative-path-in-alphaimageloader/ (stop the page after loading, it does some useless redirection)

Comment: Uh, that page says it only happens if you're using that weird alpha transparency hack. It's not a general IE issue, it's a bug with some particular odd CSS declaration.