# CSS image pathing when sourced from a different host using IE

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, azure

*[Setup: ASP.NET MVC 3 on Azure with Azure Blob Storage for CSS files and assets over HTTPS]*

I'm currently creating a website that selects an appropriate CSS style sheet depending on the host being selected - this allows the website to be enabled for different branding all altered by the CSS, but controlled by the referring host.  The mechanism uses an MVC controller that detects the host, then redirects (using an ASP.NET rewrite rule) to reference the CSS file and associated assets (i.e. images) from a separate location.  For example:

> Requests from **www.host1.com** will reference a CSS file from
>   myCssAndAssets.mycoreserver.com/css/**www.host1.com**
>
> Requests from **www.host2.com** will reference a CSS file from
>   myCssAndAssets.mycoreserver.com/css/**www.host2.com**

This works perfectly apart from one minor issue, things break when using Internet Explorer.  In short, Internet Explorer successfully obtains the CSS file, but it cannot reference any images that are referenced in that file.  Here, all images are referenced using a relative path to the actual CSS file, the assumption being that (from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-css2-971104/syndata.html#h-4.2.4))...

> Partial URLs (as defined in [RFC1808]) are interpreted relative to the
>   base URL of the style sheet, not relative to the base URL of the
>   source document.

An example of the pathing used (where the file is in the same directory as the Css file that has been redirected to)...

```
background-image: url('icon-big-buttons.png');
```

In Chrome and Firefox, things behave as expected where the image is retreived from the same location as the CSS file.  The following is a screenshot of Fiddler - the first four entries are from IE, the last three are from Chrome - these requests were made from the same site.

Note: for clarification, 'Css' is the controller MVC site that then redirects to the CSS file in Azure Blob Storage.

[image: Internet Explorer mushing things up!]

Here the IE is assuming that the images are hosted on the source host whereas Chrome correctly references the images from the location of the CSS file.

This feels very much like a IE client-side issue but my searches (while hardly exhaustive) have not been fruitful.  I know I could use absolute pathing but this is something I want to avoid as there could be a large number of CSS files to maintain...

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Comment: You're right to think that relative paths put in a CSS file are relative to that CSS file's path. I don't know anything about any version of IE behaving differently than that.

Comment: Well, I did find this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7366516/698427) but nothing further to explain or mitigate...

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem is located somewhere else. That kind of issue would be largely documented if it ever was real and would have been fixed anyway. There is obviously a problem occuring only on IE for some reason, but I doubt it is related to relative paths in CSS files. Better start looking for another possible cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lunchtime pizza I took a fresh look at the problem as per BartDude's advice - this time specifically looking at the Rewrite rules and as it appears it was these that were causing the problem after running a sanitised test.

In short, I used a rewrite rule to redirect from the core site over to the CSS and assets.  For all browsers but IE this worked fine.  Without performing the redirect, but directly referencing the Css and assets - IE played nice.

My solution was to utilise a second rewrite rule, so one to redirect the CSS and another to path to the actual assets.  This rule would then bypass the controller and navigate to the appropriate host.

```
<rules>
    <!-- first rule used to redirect from the controller to the style sheet -->
    <rule name="csstoazure" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="css-source/(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://myCssAndAssets.blob.core.windows.net/css/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <!-- second rule to capture images referenced in the style sheet but using the host name -->
    <rule name="cssieplayingnice" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="Css\/(.*\.png|.*\.gif|.*\.jpg|.*\.eot|.*\.htc)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://myCssAndAssets.blob.core.windows.net/css/{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Hope this may help others...